# Can I Restrict "Add Items" Permission

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Hi
I am been looking at the different permissions and I am wondering is it possible to restrict what a person can add?

I just see "add Item" and this seems to allow a user to add anything. Weere I want some users to be only able to add a "page" were other users can add a "page" and a "category"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought. If we go to the root site -> site settings -> Site permissions. you will be listed with site permissions of the site. Clicking on settings of the list, you get Permission levels, where you can add a new permission level.

In your case, there can be 2 permission levels created - one which allows adding items to lists and other which allows adding pages. These permissions can be used while creating users or groups to assign permissions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to make a custom permission level but I just get a choice of stuff like "add" and that allows creation of paging and categories it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event receiver to the list, and if they try to add something of the wrong content type, cancel the add in the event receiver.